# How can you delete data after each output in django?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm building a scraper that prints out the results on the same page, but whenever I try to search for new results, the old ones still appear. Meaning that the HTML doesn't get deleted at all after each search. I want that the data of the previous emails searched gets deleted for new ones. How can you do that?

The code for printing emails:

```
{% for email in email_list %}
<p id="results"> {{ email }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Email list:

```
def scrape(request):
    url = request.GET.get('Email')
    crawl = EmailCrawler(url)
    target = crawl.crawl()
    email_list = crawl.emails # or whatever class-level variable you use
    return render(request, 'leadfinderapp/emailsearcher.html', {"email_list": email_list})
```

For you to understand it better I will put two images:

[image: So this would be the first domain introduced]

[image: Second domain searched]

As you can see by the images, the first domains results appear correctly (which would be 3 emails) and the second domains results also appear, but it appears with the results of the first search. I want it to reset the results of the first instead and search for the new ones.

Comment: if you are using ajax, then in success part add this script.   $('#results').load(location.href + " #results>*", "")    this will reload 'results' div.

Comment: not using Ajax, I'm using Django features for it

Comment: do you want to delete all previous emails every time the user enters a new domain name?

Comment: yes i want to do that